# Trying to add a new Tab in Allure report

Tags: allure

I'm trying to create a plugin for Allure, that will add a new tab called Browsers, that will display TC statuses across all browsers, but I'm stuck at the first step of it - adding Browsers Tab to the report itself. I was using allure-report-plugin-api and instructions from this question - [Allure: How do I customize the test report to write "Browsers" instead of "Xunit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730865/allure-how-do-i-customize-the-test-report-to-write-browsers-instead-of-xunit) and examples from the git repo of the allure-report-plugin-api. 
But I have no luck, the tab isn't added, despite the code being so simple. Could you, please, point me where I did mistakes and show me what is the correct way to do it? Big thanks in advance!

Here's an example how I'm trying to add the new tab

Here's the project structure

```
src
--->main
--->--->java
--->--->--->allure
--->--->--->--->(Class) BrowserInfo
--->--->resourses
--->--->--->(directory)allure
--->--->--->--->(directory)BrowserInfo
--->--->--->--->--->en.json
--->--->--->--->--->script.js
--->test
--->--->allure
--->--->--->(Class) GoogleSearchTest
--->--->testcases
--->--->--->SearchTest.xml
pom.xml
```

Here's BrowserInfo class

```
package allure;

import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.Allure;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureAttachment;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureStep;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureTestCase;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.plugins.DefaultTabPlugin;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.plugins.Plugin;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.Label;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Plugin.Name("browserList")
public class BrowserInfo extends DefaultTabPlugin {

    @Override
    public void process(AllureTestCase data) {

    }

}
```

Here's en.json

```
{
  "browserList": {
    "TITLE": "Browsers",
    "TITLE_FULL": "List of browsers"
  }
}
```

Here's script.js

```
/*global angular*/
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var module = angular.module('allure.browserList', []);
    module.config(function($stateProvider, allureTabsProvider) {
        allureTabsProvider.addTab('browserList', {title: 'browserList.TITLE'});
    });

})();
```

Here's just a little test

```
package allure;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleSearchTest {

    @Test
    public void searchBananasTest() {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("BANANAS");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type = 'submit']")).click();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(
                By.cssSelector("[data-async-context='query:BANANAS'] h3")
        ).getText().toLowerCase().contains("banana"));
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Here's TestNG test xml for the test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="searching bananas">

    <test name="searching bananas" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="allure.GoogleSearchTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name = "searchBananasTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Here's pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>AllurePluginTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>AllurePluginTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>allure</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.5</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.16</allure.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suitexml}</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
      <version>${allure.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-report-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.16</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that Allure loads plugins via [Java SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html). So you need to create file
`ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.plugins.Plugin` in `META-INF/services/` in your resources folder with the following content:

```
allure.BrowserInfo
```

Then you need to configure `allure-maven-plugin` to use your plugin:

```
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**Note: the plugin should be installed to local repository.**

I recommend to use the separate project for your plugin and generate the preview report using [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/). In this case you no need to run tests (you can just place test results to folder you need) and no need to install/deploy plugin.

And few more comments for you:

#### BrowserInfo

By default Allure expects that each plugin provides some data in file `${pluginName}.json`. So you need to add some dummy data. An example you can simple add field like this:

```
@Plugin.Data
private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

The other way configure this behavior in `script.js` (empty resolve section):

```
allureTabsProvider.addTab('browserList', {title: 'browserList.TITLE', resolve: {}});
```

#### Translation

To add translation to the report use the following command:

```
allureTabsProvider.addTranslation('cats');
```

Take a look: [Allure JavaScript API](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-report-face/src/main/webapp/js/pluginApi.js)

#### Plugin template

Allure looks for `tab.tpl.html` for each tab plugin. So you need to add it to your plugin resources.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your very fast response. That helped a lot! Marking this as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! You can also use our gitter chat https://gitter.im/allure-framework/allure-core

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies ALlure Report Builder then add below code

```
// It will generate the Allure Report folder.
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("target/allure-report")).unpackFace(); 
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("target/allure-report")).processResults(new File("target/allure-results"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Searched a lot but somehow the information related to allure2 was not readily available. Thus adding a link to add a new tab in allure2:

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/blob/main/content/plugins/overview.md